# Setting background image baed on number of array or object items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, oop

I am trying to append and set the background image of divs based on the number of array items or object items(both do the same thing so I want to use one or the other).  However, when I do this, the divs are being added to the parent div correctly, but only one image is being added to all of them, only three divs should have the same background image but I'm seeing the same for all of them.  Can anyone explain why?

**JS**

This is the version using an array.

```
var plane_images = ["images/Top.png", "images/ata21.png", "images/ata26.png", "images/Top.png", "images/Top.png"];

for(var img = 0; img < plane_images.length; img++){
    $("#menu").append("<div class='schematics'></div>");
    $(".schematics").css("background-image", "url(" +plane_images[img] +")");
    console.log(plane_images[img]);
}
```

This is the object oriented version.

```
var Plane_Images = {
    top: "images/Top.png",
    structure: "images/ata21.png",
    electrics: "images/ata26.png",
    fuel: "images/Top.png",
    hydraulics: "images/Top.png"
}

for(var images in Plane_Images){
    var image_src = Plane_Images[images];

    $("#menu").append("<div class='schematics'></div>");
    $(".schematics").css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")");
    console.log(image_src); 
}
```

One thing I should note is that each of the console logs are showing me the correct values being passed.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="plane_image"></div>
        <div id="sub_menu"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$(".schematics")` selects all divs with class `.schematics` not only the one you've created in the line above ;)

Comment: @Andreas so do I need to add an `each(function(){})` in there?

Comment: I've put my comment in an answer as it is slightly more readable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding the element, then immediately selecting it, you can create the elements one by one and style them before adding them to the DOM.

```
$menu = $("#menu");

for(var images in Plane_Images){
  var image_src = Plane_Images[images];
  $schematic = $("<div></div>");
  $schematic.addClass("schematics");
  $schematic.css("background-image", "url(" + image_src +")");
  // you can log the element to the console to debug it here
  console.log($schematic);

  $menu.append($schematic);
}
```

This approach also caches the menu element to provide spending extra time evaluating the jQuery selector every iteration of the loop, so it will work faster too.

---

Similarly, if you want to use an Array rather than an object then you can make use of the jQuery [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method

```
$.each(Plane_Images, function(image_src) {
  $schematic = $("<div></div>");
  $schematic.addClass("schematics");
  $schematic.css("background-image", "url(" + image_src +")");

  $menu.append($schematic);
});
```

Comment: `Plane_Images` is an object. Look at the second part of the question.

Comment: @charlietfl, he's addressing the object oriented version with this answer

Comment: oops my bad only saw the array

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu").append("<div class='schematics'></div>");
$(".schematics").css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")");
```

You are selecting all elements with class `.schematics` and not only the one you've created just before.

This should work:

```
for(var images in Plane_Images){
    var image_src = Plane_Images[images];

    $("<div class='schematics'></div>")    // create a new div with class "schematics"
        .css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")")    // set the image as background
        .appendTo("#menu");    // append this new div to #menu

    console.log(image_src); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IDs:

```
var Plane_Images = {
  top: "images/Top.png",
  structure: "images/ata21.png",
  electrics: "images/ata26.png",
  fuel: "images/Top.png",
  hydraulics: "images/Top.png"
}

var i=1;
for(var images in Plane_Images){
  var image_src = Plane_Images[images];

  $("#menu").append("<div class='schematics' id='bgImage"+i+"'></div>"); // add ID
  $("#bgImage"+i).css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")"); // reference ID not class
  console.log(image_src); 
  i++; // increase i so no multiple IDs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your are setting background on the base of class that why the last images overriding all divs background. please use id for it like

```
for(var img = 0; img < plane_images.length; img++){
    $("#menu").append("<div class='schematics'"+i+"></div>");
    $("#schematics"+i).css("background-image", "url(" +plane_images[img] +")");
    console.log(plane_images[img]);
}
```